# What is this Authentication model called in the ASP.NET world

Tags: asp.net, .net, security

I know ASP.NET supports various authentication models like, Windows, Forms, passports and recently Claims.

I have an asp.net that prompts user to enter user name/password to login, it then compares the input username/password with the entries inside the user table of the application's Database. So, my question is, what is the term/name for this kind of authentication model? Where does this fall in the above mentioned ASP.NET supported authentication model?

I also see that many of the internet sites that I know uses this same approach.

(note: I'ev kept my App simple, of course it has user registeration/add page, profile table to authorize users, etc)

Comment: But I do not set `<authentication mode="Forms">` in the web.config

Comment: Do you make the user enter their password for each page request?  If not, you are storing their authentication values somehow.  How are you doing that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows, Forms, Passport, Claims, etc.. authentication are *BROWSER* authentication schemes.  They are the mechanism the browser communicates with the server to present credentials.  They have nothing to do with databases or any other storage mechanism (well, mostly..).  Those are just implementation details.

FormsAuthentication uses a cookie to store an encrypted value that tells the server that the user has been authenticated.  How the user is authenticated, be it by comparing things to databases, using a service, etc.. is all irrelevant if the end result is that a FormsAuthentication cookie is issued.

WindowsAuthentication is a little different in that the browser and the web server communicate to share a Kerberos ticket to verify identity, or the user enters the username password into a box that the server requests the browser to pop up.  In this mode, the server itself manages the way that authentication occurs and the app isn't involved.

BasicAuthentication uses an HTTP Header to send the password in cleartext, well, technically it's an encoded password, but it's well known so anyone can unencode it.  Again, the actual method that it stores the data is up to the server, and the server does this without an applications knowledge.  The important part is that it's accomplished via an HTTP Header.

The same is true of other types of authentication, which are all just variations on the cookie and/or header mechanisms.

The point here is that Authentication is about how any given HTTP request identifies who the user is to the server, and ultimately the application.  Not how the data is stored, or validated.  So, since you did not tell us how the server and browser communicate, we can't tell you how your authentication is defined, although almost certainly it is a variation of FormsAuthentication.

EDIT:

Just a little history lesson.  The reason it's called FormsAuthentication is because the authentication system does not use a pop up dialog box from the browser to enter credentials, but typically the web page provides an HTML Form for the user to enter credentials.  The browser is not really involved in the authentication process at all, other than for passing a cookie as requested.

It should be more accurately called "CookieBasedAuthentication", but the name has stuck and will probably stay what it is.  ASP.NET provides a specific implementation called FormsAuthentication, but you can do the same thing with any cookie based authentication scheme (although I do not recommend rolling your own, you will almost certainly make security mistakes).

Some people think that storing a flag in Session is good enough.  Do not, under any circumstances, ever use Session to store authentication information.  Session cookies are not encrypted and are easily stolen and/or spoofed.  Use a well known method.

Comment: Great answer.  This is absolutely correct.  Thanks for taking the time to go into so much detail.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers might have already showed most of the details. But if we categorize carefully on IIS and ASP.NET levels, below are the differences you should pay attention to,

---

IIS Authentication

This occurs first, as HTTP packets arrive at IIS level first. IIS supports several ways,

- Anonymous (the anonymous user account configured in IIS configuration)
- Windows (browser side user)
- Basic (browser side user)
- Digest (browser side user)

How those authentication methods work at packet level requires you to capture network packets and dive into the conversation at that level.

The result of this authentication is that IIS generates a user token and passes on to ASP.NET pipeline.

---

ASP.NET Authentication

ASP.NET has several authentication methods of its own,

- Windows (here ASP.NET trusts and interprets the user token IIS passes, and determines which ASP.NET user identity should be created and which roles it supports, without doing further authentication on ASP.NET level.)
- Forms (based) authentication (where ASP.NET ignores the user token, and uses cookies or similar mechanism to build a high level authentication approach. On IIS side you usually set anonymous authentication.)
- Claims based authentication, OpenID, OAthen and so on are similar to Forms based, where they don't care much about the user token generated by IIS.

It is possible to use non-anonymous on IIS plus non-Windows on ASP.NET side to set up the so called mixed authentication.

Answer (score 1):

All the Authentication methods that require the user to input a Username and Password that you maintain are a form of Forms Authentication.  This is because you are asking them to fill out a form (Username and Password) in order to authenticate them.

Read more about it [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form-based_authentication) or [Here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4.aspx)

Edit:  The answer provided by Mystere Man is much more complete and accurate than mine.